# Python logging doesn't work when script is called from another program

Tags: python, python-logging

I have a python script that I use with LibreOffice Calc to do some more advanced macros.  I need to debug this script and I'm trying to use logging for this. Logging works fine when the script is called from the command line, but it doesn't work at all when the script is called by LibreOffice.

Here is my logging test code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', level=logging.INFO)
logging.warning('test')
```

As requested, here is the LibreOffice Basic script that calls the Python script (this was mostly just a copy/paste from a guide on how to call Python scripts from LO):

```
function cev(a as String) as double
Dim scriptPro As Object, myScript As Object
Dim a1(1), b1(0), c1(0) as variant
a1(0) = ThisComponent
a1(1) = a
scriptPro = ThisComponent.getScriptProvider()
myScript = scriptPro.getScript( _
       "vnd.sun.star.script:Cell_Functions.py$calcEffectValue?language=Python&location=user")
cev = myScript.invoke(a1, b1, c1)
end function
```

The basic script is called on a single cell using CEV(cellAddress), which passes the contents of the cell through to the Python script as a string.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about the file setup and the script that calls the code that contains the logging part?

Comment: Added the basic script.  As for file setup - AFAIK the basic scripts are baked into the Calc document.  The Python script is in its default location:  "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\LibreOffice\4\user\Scripts\python"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I updated to LibreOffice 7 and this started working. The Python version in LO 7 is 3.8 instead of 3.5, so maybe that made the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is working but you just don't know where `test.log` file is getting placed when it runs from LibreOffice. Try providing an absolute file path for `test.log`, like let's say `C:/test.log`.

Comment: I have tried the default (script parent directory) and an absolute file path.  Both work when run from command line - neither work when run from LibreOffice.

Comment: @synthc Is there an error message? Does it silently not work?

Comment: No error; it just does nothing.  Doesn't even create the log file.

Comment: How do you know it runs at all? All it does is logging which presumably doesn't work. Can you make it do something else you can check to make sure the script is actually running?

Comment: That is not the entire script; just the logging code at the start of it.  I know the script runs and works because it returns values in my spreadsheet.

Comment: @synthc my guess is still the same. I bet the logging file is being created but it is placed in a location that is hard to guess. If you give it a really weird unique name and search for it across the entire harddrive, I bet you'll find it. This might help: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/sq/text/sbasic/python/python_locations.html

Comment: If it creates the log file at the specified location when running from command line/any IDE, why would it put it somewhere else when running from LibreOffice?

Comment: I did a search of the entire drive anyway just to be sure and the file does not exist.